# Date in Text Field with Virtual Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have already asked a similar question on this, however after seeing the railscast on using textfields - Ryan recommends using a virtual attribute.

I have set up my model with the virtual attribute like so:

```
attr_accessible :title, :description, :start, :start_string

def start_string
  unless start.nil?
    start.to_s(:db)
  end
end

def start_string(start_str)
  self.start = Date.parse(start_str)
rescue ArgumentError
  @start_invalid = true
end

def validate
  errors.add(:start, "is invalid") if @start_invalid
end
```

I have included this in my edit view like so:

```
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :start_string %> <br />
        <%= f.text_field :start_string %>
        <%#= f.date_select(:start, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :end_year => Time.now.year + 10) %>
    </div>
```

However, I get an error when loading my edit form

```
    wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I also know this is a very old railscast and someone event comments:

> "As Rayn mentioned if you add nil? check on the getter method it should wotk fine!"
>
> No. The code is outdated for use today. There are more efficient ways
>   to do this now

So what is the proper way to do this now? Seems like an easy and straight forward way to do it...if I wasn't getting an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method should be `def start_string=(start_str)` (you're missing the equals sign).

Comment: sloppy sloppy - thanks for catching that for me. However, for some reason though Time.parse(start_str) will reject a date input like 3/30/2013 and it interprets 1/12/2013 as December 1, 2013 - does Time.parse or Date.parse not handle inputs in the standard american way?

Comment: Perhaps I need Chronic's Parse method?

Comment: Nope, because of Ruby's Japanese origins (where they do the day/month/year format) it will always do it that way. You could use something like [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) which will let you do `Chronic.parse(start_str)`. Otherwise, you would need to either override `Date.parse` to do what you want, or make a custom method and call that instead.

Comment: Another option is `Date.strptime(start_str, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Many thanks - just added Chronic and it is really really really useful  - I like all the options it affords. I'm leary of getting to "gem heavy" though, but this one seems very useful.